# Noisy Fan Ubuntu 12.10, not that noisy on Windows

Tags: 12.10, dell, fancontrol

I am using a Dell Inspiron 7520. I have a AMD Radeon HD 7730m working in switching with an Intel HD 4000. I have the lastest drivers from AMD so my switching is working flawlessly. I have made some script described in another post :

```
sleep 5 && echo "min_power" | tee /sys/class/scsi_host/host*/link_power_management_policy
```

usually, I am using

```
echo "min_power" | tee /sys/class/scsi_host/host*/link_power_management_policy
```

It worked fine with the open source graphic driver but right now on the performance GPU my fan is always running. It is good for the hardware but not for me after a while.

Thank you!

P.S I don't know if it could be of any use, I run my interface with gnome classic, I have installed gnome-shell then changed my interface from there to get more performance on EVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same notebook as yours, and the solution for me was 'i8kutils'.

```
sudo apt-get install i8kutils
```

In this package the script 'i8kmon' is for automatic control.

Some tips are:

```
Put 'ENABLED=1' in '/etc/default/i8kmon'
Put 'set config(auto) 1' in '/etc/i8kmon.conf'
```

I hope it helps.